# While loop doesn't exit

Tags: python

while loop does not exit

```
import random
secret_num = random.randint(1, 10)
guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
while guess != secret_num:
    guess = input("Please try again: ")
print("Done!")
```

Comment: Try guess = int(input("Please try again: "))

Comment: This is a duplicate question but I just can't seem to find it

Comment: I mean although a have guessed all numbers in range of 1 to 10. while loop doesn't exiting loop continues...i have printed actual secret_num and tried that as guess still while loop doesn't exiting..

Comment: Topic says nothing, post text says nothing. I won't read code to guess what is your problem. Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @DarrylG, you have to convert the input to int.

```
import random
secret_num = random.randint(1, 10)
guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
while guess != secret_num:
    guess = int(input("Please try again: "))
print("Done!")
```

But remember its random, so you need to try atmax 9 times, to get out of loop.